# Replacing "it" with "that" in some cases? Is that okay?

Tags: grammar

Someone on Facebook said that iPhone 7 doesn't have features according the price.

So I said:

> Go for Galaxy S8. **That** even has fast-charging feature.

Is it right to replace *it* with *that* here?

Answer (score 1):

We use **that** commonly to point to a thing or person with singular nouns when the thing or person is often distant/invisible from the speaker. For example:
*That’s* Steven in the blue shirt, isn’t it? (pronoun)
As in the your sentence; *Go for galaxy s8. That even has fast charging feature*

- **that** also plays here a role of pronoun for *galaxy s8* you have mentioned in the preceding sentence. Also, you can use **it**. It's fine.
- Your sentence is right.

Comment: I thought that isn't a complete pronoun. Like i have to use a noun after that.   Like i love that apples ,i hate that girl. Does it work as a complete pronoun as well?

Answer (score 0):

"It" and "that" both work here, but your sentence needs more articles.  It should be one of the following:

> Go for **the** Galaxy S8. That even has **a** fast-charging feature.
>
> Go for **the** Galaxy S8. It even has **a** fast-charging feature.

"**A** Galaxy S8" could work, too, and "**the** fast-charging feature" could work, especially if it's a feature that's been previously mentioned or discussed or which has been much mentioned elsewhere (so that the reader is likely to be familiar with it even if it's not been mentioned in the conversation).

Also, "a fast-charge feature" would perhaps sound better than "a fast-charging feature", though both are correct.  It's also possible to omit the word "feature" and just say "fast charging" on its own.  Here, the article wouldn't be needed: "That has fast charging."